# What is the MPI data type equivalent to off_t?

Tags: c, mpi

I would like to send/receive a vector of type `off_t` using MPI, but I've been reading that `off_t` type can be different things in different platforms. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use something "sufficiently large" instead, perhaps `int64_t` if you need the range of most modern general-purpose operating systems.

Of course, that'd probably mean you need to manually convert, to make it type-safe all the way, which might be costly if you're doing this for large vectors.

Comment: The manual conversion can be conditional on the sizes being different, so no overhead for the common case.